# Why can Windsor only intercept virtual or interfaced methods?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, interceptor

I'm reading the documentation and see that if you don't use an interface then Windsor can only intercept virtual methods?

Is this a limitation with Windsor or simply the C# language? I'm looking for an in depth answer.

Comment: I'm new to this technology too. Just got caught with this mistake, didn't made method virtual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# language is completely irrelevant here. The question is how the interception works at the runtime level.

One technique is inheriting from the class/implementing the interface and using that as a proxy. This can obviously only override virtual methods and interface methods. I suspect Windsor uses this technique. The advantage of this technique is that it doesn't need anything special. Just create a class at runtime.

Another way is using the profiling API. This allows you to modify the IL of any method, including non virtual ones. This is much more intrusive, and typically only used when testing legacy code.

Yet another way is using IL rewriting at build time. This can add interception points in code you wrote, but not in framework code.

Comment: You are right, Windsor Intercepor are Dynamic Proxy: http://kozmic.pl/dynamic-proxy-tutorial/

Comment: Acutally -1. IL overwiting is standard also for well designed code.... I can not leave my classes open for subclassing when designing an API (bad proramming practice) just because a mocking tool is too stupid to deal with nicely sealed classes.

Answer (score 2):

Neither nor. Windsor works by subclassing and you can only override virtual methods sensibly - or interfaces can be implemented.

Anything else requires debugger/profiler hooks active and that is hard to do - some mocking frameworks support, ti, though none of them are free.

Comment: I think Microsoft Moles is free and can do this. But I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Moles is retired. It is now called "Fakes" and part of Visual Studio 11 ;) http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/

Answer (score 2):

It's a limitation of the .NET framework.  Windsor produces a dynamic implementation, which either implements an interface or overrides a virtual member.  .NET does not allow members that are not virtual to be overridden.

Comment: -1. It is a limitation o an inferior technology on the mocking side. Quite some commercial frameworks do it right.

Comment: @TomTom can you name the frameworks that do it please, I'd like to check them out, thanks

Comment: Telerik JustMock has two modes - one via proxy, one via IL replacement. it is also not very expensive. There is another one, but it is 2500 USD per machine - including build servers.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you need virtuals but that is just because Microsoft has screwed up this behavior, if you look at Java for instance a method is open for extension by default, you have to explictly mark it as sealed.

Read more on SOLID principles, specificly Open Closed Principle.

Comment: -1. So how you subbclass a selaed method in Java? Stop the religious war - there are good reasons during testing to mock sealed methods and good frameworks support this.

Comment: It's not a religious thing TomTom, and yes if it supported code weaving all would be great, i am just indicating that it might be a good practise to follow the open closed principle in your code, if you don't want to, be my guest :)

Comment: Sure. Just keepingclases opn - in violation of requirements of the project (closed API) only to facilitate unit testing is a limitation of bad mocking frameworks. Good ones even can replace NEW constructs in a class with another class.

Comment: @TomTom you do know that windsor is not a mocking framework right ?