# Why do my interceptors not called when using the proxy?

Tags: c#, proxy, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm trying to use Castle DynamicProxy, but the most basic piece of code inspired from tutorials such as [this one](https://richardwilburn.wordpress.com/2009/12/17/using-castles-dynamic-proxy/) fails.

In order to make things simpler, I've put *all* the code in one file, so it would be short enough to copy-paste here:

```
namespace UnitTests
{
    using Castle.DynamicProxy;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using System;

    [TestClass]
    public class DemoTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestHelloMethodThroughProxy()
        {
            var proxy = new ProxyGenerator().CreateClassProxy<Demo>(new DemoInterceptor());
            var actual = proxy.SayHello();
            var expected = "Something other";

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class DemoInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            invocation.ReturnValue = "Something other";
        }
    }

    public class Demo
    {
        public string SayHello()
        {
            return "Hello, World!";
        }
    }
}
```

The code consists of a single unit test which generates a proxy of a class, and then calls a method of this class through the proxy.

The proxy is intended to circumvent the call to the original method by simply assigning a result value, without calling the original method.

If I replace `invocation.ReturnValue = "Something other";` by `throw new NotImplementedException();`, the result of the test is still exactly the same, and the exception is not thrown, indicating that the code is probably not called. In debug mode, breakpoints within the `Intercept` method are not reached either.

What do I need to do in order for the interceptors to be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Castle Windsor can intercept only interface or virtual members. Your `Demo.SayHello` method is not marked as virtual and thus it is not intercepted.

Either mark the method as virtual or work with interfaces.

Refer [Why can Windsor only intercept virtual or interfaced methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576434/why-can-windsor-only-intercept-virtual-or-interfaced-methods)